# Compute Multiple Means in Dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe with 2 columns. A quality score, and an outcomes. Outcomes are either `1` or `0`. Quality Scores are different integers from 1 - 135. This is a snapshot of the dataframe:

[image]

For each quality score, I would like to compute the mean. I can do it for one Quality Score at a time as such:

`test <- subset(deletion_qs, qs == 10)`
`sum(test$outcomes)/length(test$outcomes)`
`[1] 0.4`

But this is too slow. I was wondering if there is a way using one of the `apply` functions?

Here is the data:

`quality_score <- c(2, 1  ,18  , 1  , 2  , 1  , 1 ,  1  , 2 ,  1,   1  , 1  , 1 ,  1  ,10 , 10  ,10,  10 , 10 , 10 , 10 , 10,  10 , 10 ,  1  ,29 ,1 , 29  ,63  , 1  ,25 ,  1  , 1  ,52  ,28  , 1 ,  1  ,10 ,  3,  28  , 1 , 20,   1, 10, 1 , 10 ,  3  , 1  , 3 , 10  ,10 , 56 , 1,   1,   2 ,  3 ,  2 ,  1 ,  1,  44 ,  1 ,  1,  10 , 33 , 67  ,67,  19  , 8 , 39,  10 ,  2  , 1 , 42 , 22,   7 , 93 ,  1  , 12 , 10 ,135 ,  1 , 31 ,  6 , 16,  15 ,  1 , 35 ,  1,  10 , 10)`

`outcome <- c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0,
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1)`

Comment: I think you are looking for `aggregate(outcome ~ qs, data=df, mean)`.

Comment: I think there is a problem with your data, 90 (quality_score) and 91 (outcome) elements. They should be of equal length.

Answer (score 1):

You can use dplyr group_by and summarise
Combine first to "tot.data". Then

library(dplyr)

group_by(tot.data, quality_score) %>% summarise(Mean1 = mean(outcome))